# Meteor dburles:maps package adding geolocation

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, meteor

I am using the Meteor `dburles:maps` package and am trying to implement the `geolocation` feature from the Google Maps API, but I can't seem to figure how to go about it. I have the following JS and HTML structure:

**.html**

```
<template name="map">
  <div class="map-container">
    {{> googleMap name="map" options=mapOptions}}
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="search">
      <input id="search" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

**.js**

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
  GoogleMaps.load();
});

Template.map.helpers({
  mapOptions: function() {
    if (GoogleMaps.loaded()) {
      return {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-37.8136, 144.9631),
        zoom: 8
      };
    }
  }
});

Template.map.onCreated(function() {
  GoogleMaps.ready('map', function(map) {

    if(navigator.geolocation) {
      // Support
    } else {
      // No support
    }

  })
})
```

I think I have to interact with the API within the `Template.map.onCreated`, but I can't seem to figure out exactly what to add. I have looked at the google maps docs, but the structure is different, as there are somethings that the package does under the hood. Anyone that has encountered this problem and solved it?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Insert geolocation, so the map loads with the current location of the user.

Answer (score 0):

First you'll want to add the required packages:

```
meteor add mdg:geolocation
```

Change the mapOptions Helper to:

```
Template.map.helpers({
  mapOptions: function() {
    var latLng = Geolocation.latLng();
    // Initialize the map once we have the latLng.
    if (GoogleMaps.loaded() && latLng) {
      return {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(latLng.lat, latLng.lng),
        zoom: MAP_ZOOM
      };
    }
  }
});
```